# Algebraic Extension in which every element has nontrivial isotropy group

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I've been trying to come up with an example of the following problem, but have been unable to do so. Any ideas?

Construct an algebraic extension $K$ of a field $k$ such that every the isotropy group $G_\alpha$ is nontrivial for every $\alpha\in K$.

This is an old preliminary exam [here](http://math.northwestern.edu/graduate/prelims/alg-12.pdf).